# Javascript Variable value being deleted? (Probably not, but it seems like it)

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am trying to make a simple dieting calculator with my limited HTML, CSS, and JS knowledge. While I was partway through coding the Javascript (the third step for the user out of five), my third variable was returning as 0, when it should return as something else (~10-15) My logic works like this:

> A user clicks a button from a group that specifies to them.
>
> > For the first function, `st1 = (a number that specifies on which button is pressed)`
> > Do note that at the start of the js, the variables are already declared (`let st1 = 0; let st2 = 0; etc.`)
> >
> > > For the second function, `st2 = parseInt(st1) + (another number)`
> > >
> > > > The same thing happens for the 3rd function
> > > >
> > > > > I have not finished the rest

I have tried `console.log()`ing `st2` when the third step is called, and it returns as 0. Thanks for any help!

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p id="step1">Step 1.</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                Gender:
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="Male()">Male</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="Female()">Female</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="Other()">Other/Prefer Not to say</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p id="step2">Step 2.</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                Age:
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="seventeen()">Between 17-26</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="twentyseven()">Between 27-37</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="thirtyeight()">Between 38-47</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="fortyeight()">Between 48-57</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="fiftyeight()">Over 58</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p id="step3">Step 3.</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                Height
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="under5()">Below 5ft</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="btwn()">Between 5'0" - 5'9"</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="over()">Over 5'10"</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the JS:

```
let st1 = 0;
let st2 = 0;
let st3 = 0;

//Start Group one, these three functions are each called when clicking a button with the user's gender
function Male() {
    st1 = 8;
    document.getElementById("step1").innerHTML = "Complete";
    console.log(st1);
}

function Female() {
    st1 = 2;
    document.getElementById("step1").innerHTML = "Complete";
    console.log(st1);
}

function Other() {
    st1 = 4;
    document.getElementById("step1").innerHTML = "Complete";
    console.log(st1);
}
//End Group one
//Start group two, each of these are called when the user clicks a button with their age group.
function seventeen() {
    let st2 = parseInt(st1) + 4;
    document.getElementById("step2").innerHTML = "Complete";
    console.log(st2)
}

function twentyseven() {
    let st2 = parseInt(st1) + 3;
    document.getElementById("step2").innerHTML = "Complete";
    console.log(st2);
}

function thirtyeight() {
    let st2 = parseInt(st1) + 2;
    document.getElementById("step2").innerHTML = "Complete"
    console.log(st2);
}

function fortyeight() {
    let st2 = parseInt(st1) + 1;
    document.getElementById("step2").innerHTML = "Complete"
    console.log(st2);
}

function fiftyeight() {
    let st2 = parseInt(st1) + 0;
    document.getElementById("step2").innerHTML = "Complete"
    console.log(st2)
}
//End group 2
//Start Group 3, The user clicks a button with their height range.
function under5() {
    let st3 = st2 + 0;
    document.getElementById("step3").innerHTML = "Complete";
    console.log(st3);
}

function btwn() {
    let st3 = parseInt(st2) + 1;
    document.getElementById("step3").innerHTML = "Complete";
    console.log(st3);
}

function over() {
    let st3 = parseInt(st2) + 2 ;
    document.getElementById("step3").innerHTML = "Complete";
    console.log(st3);
}
//End group 3
//There are two more groups I haven't finished coding, so won't include here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you put the keyword `let` before the variable, it gets redeclared. try removing the `let`s from the functions.

also, you could do something like this, though there are even better ways...

```
<button onclick="gender(8)">Male</button>
<button onclick="gender(2)">Female</button>

function gender( value ) {
    std1 = value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help, and the suggestion for making my code cleaner!